# Capturar todas as Sextas e Domingos e Quartas entre duas datas

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Estou tentando capturar todas as sextas-feiras, domingos e quartas feiras entre duas datas, usando o Moment.js. Eu não consegui entender porque não captura os dias:

-08/12/2021
-10/12/2021

já que cai na condição.

Eu estou tentando obter o seguinte:

```
2021-12-01 10:00:00
2021-12-01 16:00:00
2021-12-01 22:30:00
2021-12-03 10:00:00
2021-12-03 16:00:00
2021-12-03 22:30:00
2021-12-05 10:00:00
2021-12-05 16:00:00
2021-12-05 22:30:00
2021-12-08 10:00:00
2021-12-08 16:00:00
2021-12-08 22:30:00
2021-12-10 10:00:00
2021-12-10 16:00:00
2021-12-10 22:30:00
```

Segue a função:

```js
const allDays = [5, 0, 3];

function formatToPush(dt_inicio, dt_final, dia, horas) {

let start = moment(dt_inicio);
let end = moment(dt_final);

let result = [];
let datas = [];
let current = start.clone();

if ((current.day(dia).isSameOrAfter(start)) || (current.day(dia).isSameOrAfter(end)) || (current.day(7 + dia).isSameOrBefore(end))) {
    result.push(current.clone());
}

result.map(m => {
    horas.map(h => {
        m.set({ hour: h.split(':')[0], minute: h.split(':')[1], second: 0, millisecond: 0 });
        datas.push(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ'))
    })
});

return datas;
}

let final = [];

for(let i in allDays){  
  final.push(...formatToPush('2021-12-01', '2021-12-10', allDays[i], ["10:00", "16:00", "22:30"]))
}

console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Apesar de fornecer um aparente [mcve], é necessário explicar o passo a passo do funcionamento do que fez até o momento, por isso é importante [edit] e revisar essa questão. Extra: No geral que creio que isso poderia ser muito bem resolvido sem moment.js (algo que usei só em um projeto, pq era padrão por lá), mas que de fato nunca precisei.

Comment: @hkotsubo até tentei fazer, mas ainda sem sucesso.

Comment: Você está sabendo que o [Moment.js foi descontinuado em 2020](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) e o fabricante desaconselha o uso da biblioteca em novos projetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código você fez um `if` em vez de um *loop*, então ele não necessariamente vai gerar tudo, caso as datas se espalhem por mais de uma semana.

Enfim, a ideia básica é primeiro verificar se a data inicial é um dos dias da semana que você quer. Se não for, primeiro você ajusta ela para a mais próxima. Por exemplo, no seu caso você quer domingo, quarta e sexta. Então se a data inicial for segunda ou terça, ajusta para a próxima quarta. Se for quinta, ajusta para a próxima sexta. Se for sábado, ajusta para o próximo domingo, e qualquer outro dia não precisa de ajuste.

Depois, precisamos saber qual desses dias da semana é o inicial, para saber quantos dias somar até o próximo. Do domingo para a quarta, são 3 dias, nos demais casos são 2 dias (inclusive de sexta para domingo).

Por fim, tendo isso, basta fazer um loop pelas datas, pulando a quantidade necessária até o próximo dia da semana, e para cada uma dessas datas, faço outro loop pelos horários. Ficaria assim:

```js
// ajusta a data para o próximo dia da semana que está no array daysOfWeek
// retorna a data ajustada e o índice que corresponde ao dia da semana no array
function ajustaProximoDoW(data, daysOfWeek) {
    // verifica se o dia da semana está no array
    let index = daysOfWeek.findIndex(dow => data.day() === dow);
    if (index >= 0) { // se está, já retorna
        return [ data, index ];
    }
    // se não está, fazer o ajuste para o mais próximo
    let next = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
        const dow = daysOfWeek[i];
        if (data.day() > dow && data.day() < daysOfWeek[(i + 1) % daysOfWeek.length]) {
            next = daysOfWeek[(i + 1) % daysOfWeek.length];
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (next === -1) {
        next = daysOfWeek[0];
        index = 0;
        if (data.day() > daysOfWeek[daysOfWeek.length - 1]) next += 7;
    }
    data.add(next - data.day(), 'days');
    return [ data, index ];
}

function gerarIntervalo(dt_inicio, dt_final, daysOfWeek, hours) {
    // ordena os dias da semana
    daysOfWeek.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
    // ajusta a data inicial
    let [ start, index ] = ajustaProximoDoW(moment(dt_inicio), daysOfWeek);
    let end = moment(dt_final);

    // diferenças a serem adicionadas para obter a próxima data
    let diffs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
        diffs[i] = ((daysOfWeek[(i + 1) % daysOfWeek.length] + 7) - daysOfWeek[i]) % 7;
    }

    let result = [];
    // compara início e fim, ignorando o horário
    while (end.isSameOrAfter(start, 'day')) {
        for (const h of hours) {
            const [hour, minute, second] = h.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
            start.set({ hour, minute, second });
            result.push(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        }
        start.add(diffs[index], 'days');
        index = (index + 1) % diffs.length;
    }
    return result;
}

let daysOfWeek = [0, 3, 5]; // domingo, quarta e sexta
let horarios = ["10:00", "16:00", "22:30"];
console.log(gerarIntervalo('2021-12-01', '2021-12-10', daysOfWeek, horarios));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```